# How to make a Javascript file not reset when user refresh page

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on a desktop app with `node.js` and `electron`.
I need to create a `javascript` file that handles many processes, store them in a dict and never refresh the dict.
let's say that this app is used for create timers, and the user create 5 timers in the `/timers` page, at this page is bounded a script that take the inputs that the user gives, creates a new `Timer` objects and store them in the `timers_dict`. How can i store them safely without the danger that when the user refresh the page the script reset itself losing all the created timers? (without saving the datas in `.txt` or `.json` files ). Actually instea `Timers` objects i need to store some `electron windows` objects that have to be retrivied in a second moment for reuse them.

Comment: have you concidered local storage?

Comment: Electron doesn't really have local storage the way a browser does. Maybe use something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store

Comment: @JeremyHarris The timers were just an example, i need to save some electron windows objects and i don't think i can save them in a json file and retrive them directly fore be used again

Comment: make use of localStrorage, then reassign the values on page load

Comment: Doesnt this contradict the purpose of refresh? As this sounds you want to keep the v8 instance and its references - rethink this and store values in main process and on new window/ context recreate those - or move them into another instance to begin with - BrowserWindow object can be stored in main process just handle events: crash, unresponsive, close, closed etc... as object get destroyed and gc

Comment: @Estradiaz How can i archieve it in the main process?

Comment: I think a starting point is to check out IPC - then you can run a hidden window/ v8 instance managing your processes - pipe info through main process to GUI window and vice versa - but still think about a way to serialize those states into a buffer or something so you can recover on exceptions - make something explicit and we can discuss an example

Comment: if you're using node, you could create an api endpoint to ajax to to store the data, either as a saved file, or using a database - mongo or other.

Comment: JavaScript has no _dict_ actually... Json file is a good way to store persistent data. Is there a reason you don't want to store your data in a file ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by exending the broswer window class

```
class newBrowserWindow extends BrowserWindow {
    createStore() {
       this.store_values = {
        'JOBS': {}
      };
    }

    storeValue(keys, param) {
      keys = keys.split(' ');
      let dict = this.store_values

      for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        let key = keys[i];
        if (i != keys.length - 1){
          dict = dict[key];
        } else {
            dict[key] = param;
        }
      }
    }

    deleteValue(keys) {
      keys = keys.split(' ');
      let dict = this.store_values

      for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        let key = keys[i];
        if (i != keys.length - 1){
          dict = dict[key];
        } else {
            delete dict[key];
        }
      }
    }

    getStore(){
        return this.store_values;
    }
}
```

and creating a broswer window using the extendend class insteat the normal class, in this way i can store the values globally inside the window object

Comment: Consider that this is in the main process, and access is kinda readonly in renderer: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remote-objects & https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#lifetime-of-remote-objects & https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#passing-callbacks-to-the-main-process